# Определение координат элемента множества

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Есть таблица

[image: Таблица]

- Элемент 2 имеет координаты (2,1)
- Элемент 7 (3,3).
- Элемент 15 (2,4) и т.д.

Как можно определить координаты элемента N?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации  с описанием конкретных проблем.

Comment: Лабы — это не к нам.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем пытку. Так как решение перед глазами и давать его полностью не интересно.

Для старта -- Вычисление первой (одной из) координаты

Найти минимальное число Z, квадрат которого будет больше или равно заданного N.

Тогда Z будет одной координатой.

Остается понять это x или y. Ну и вычислить вторую координату.

Answer (score 0):

тут можно найти так

все числа идет в порядке 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...

когда нашли ленту, (это Г образная), делим еше на 2, он даст в начале ленты или в конце.

если в начале, значет X не меняется, если во второй половине, Y не меняется.

Думаю теперь найдете что требовалось